# Adding notes to a data file (csv) in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to capture data from an oscilloscope using a python script. The script saves it as in csv format. I need to add few lines of text describing the data at the beginning.

I looked at existing threads to see if there was a possible solution. I just started learning Python. I am using code that came with the instrument.

This is part of the script that saves the data as csv.

```
NewD = (np.insert(Wav_Data, 0, DataTime, axis = 0)).T
filename = BASE_DIRECTORY + BASE_FILE_NAME + ".csv"
now = time.time() # Only to show how long it takes to save
with open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
   np.savetxt(filename, NewD, delimiter = ',', header = column_titles)
```

I tried to use the section below from another code but am not sure how to append this to the csv file.

```
with open("notes.txt") as f:
    NOTES = f.readlines()
NOTES = "".join(NOTES)
```

It is unable to find notes.txt which is located in the same directory as the script.
Eager to hear your feedback. Thanks in advance.

**Updated to:**

```
# Save data
NewD = (np.insert(Wav_Data, 0, DataTime, axis = 0)).T
filename = BASE_DIRECTORY + BASE_FILE_NAME + ".csv"

with open("notes.txt") as f:
    NOTES = f.readlines()
NOTES = "".join(NOTES)

with open(filename, "a") as fh:
    fh.write(NOTES)

now = time.time() # Only to show how long it takes to save
with open(filename, 'w') as filehandle:
    np.savetxt(filename, NewD, delimiter = ',', header = column_titles)
```

Comment: ```open(filename, 'a')``` will append to the file instead of overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to this.

Comment: are you running the script in the same directory as notes.txt?

Comment: Yes I checked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open the file for appending or write

If you want to write CSV first then notes:

```
with open("notes.txt") as f:
    NOTES = f.readlines()
NOTES = "".join(NOTES)

with open(filename, "w") as fh:
    fh.write(NOTES)
    # this time we give np the opened filehandle, not the filename
    np.savetxt(fh, NewD, delimiter = ',', header = column_titles)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, I don't get any errors now but the text is not inserted in the csv..How can I do that?

Comment: Yes. Should I put in the full path for the notes.txt that needs to be appended to the csv?

Comment: OK. This is super confusing. CAn you A) write to filename B) read notes.txt C) verify that NOTES holds the text data that you want to append to filename

Comment: A)  and C) are true. I believe B) is also carried successfully as no errors and when I type in NOTES on the console, the output gives what's contained in the notes.txt. Only thing now is that it is not being added to the csv as I would like.

Comment: Could you update the code in your original question to show how and where you append the notes to the csv?

Comment: ah. now I see what you're doing. I'll edit my post. Your append and write are the wrong way round

Comment: Will. Thank you so much. I am able to get the csv with text preceding the data. I just need to resolve some string floating errors. Despite that the data is still being saved.